# How to add PDcurses to VS2019?

Tags: visual-studio, pdcurses

How to add PDcurses to VS2019?

"Make" and "nmake" commands not working.

Answer (score 0):

To build PDCurses:

`nmake -f Makefile.vc`

as described in the instructions. If that's not working, please give more details.

Comment: Yes it works, but how to add to Visual Studio 2019?